# Python script working in IDLE, but not working when run from CMD or Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, windows-7, cmd, python-idle

I have a rather strange problem.

When I run a python module (which imports other .py and .pyd files) from IDLE or in Debug mode from Eclipse, everything works fine and the final result is correct. But when I try to run the same module in run mode from  Eclipse or from CMD, error window appears with 'python.exe has stopped working' message.

I managed to track the error down to the conclusion, that python stops working when a function from .pyd file is called (the import works fine). From there on I have no idea, what in causing the problems.
The .pyd input arguments are in all cases the same. Yet, python crashes, when the python module is run from cmd.

I am running a 64 bit Windows7, 64bit Python 2.6.6 and all python binaries .pyc are obtained on the same computer. No other python version is installed on the computer.

I would appreciate any advice, how to be able to run the code from cmd without python.exe crashing.

Comment: pyd is a c_extension module.  Are you sure you're using the same interpreter both times?

A quick way to tell is:

import sys
print sys.executable

Comment: What does the function that causes the crash do? Also, verify which Python interpreter executable you're running. From Eclipse, go to `Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python` and check the location of the interpeter. Make sure that's the same one you're running from the command prompt. I know you said you only have one installed, but maybe some other program installed a different Python that you didn't know about, and put it in the path.

Comment: Thank you for response. The interpreted IDLE uses is pythonw.exe, the interpreter in CMD is python.exe. Both executables are in the same default folder. How can I change the python interpreter, which CMD uses?

Comment: There are two ways to do this in windows - first simply pass the script to the pythonw interpreter --

C:\python27\pythonw program.py

*or*

You can change the extension of your program from *.py to *.pyw

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem when calling the .pyd module. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem...

this function:

```
pyd_function(num.asarray(arr).astype('float64'))
```

was causing problems when I ran it inside eclipse, but not when I debugged it inside eclipse or ran it from IDLE; then I changed the call to:

```
a=num.asarray(arr).astype('float64')
pyd_function(a)
```

and it started to work. I could not figure why the first call is causing problems.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, jankos, this solved my problem. When I called the pyd_function I gave as input an expression rather than a predefined variable. My scripts are now running from CMD and Eclipse runmode. Does anybody have any idea, why this problem arised when the scripts were run in different ways?